# Create Crystal Reports in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, crystal-reports

I've searched a lot about creating a Crystal Reports in java Netbeans. but all I've seen was a plugins (iReport).

Can you guys help me, if theres a way to create a Crystal reports in Java Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can "create" Crystal Reports in NB. You can integrate existing reports. What you need to make it work is a jdbc/odbc bridge to be able to make your connection. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731385/where-can-i-find-a-good-jdbc-odbc-bridge-driver) or do a little search on jdbc/odbc. To actually call the report, take a look [here](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/other_examples/Crystal_Reports.htm). The code relies on a j-integra com bridge, which is a payware code, but you can modify the code to use your own.
From what I hear though it is much easier to use iReport or Jasper Reports.

Hope this helps,

Chris

Comment: yes sir, as the time i searched i knew that i will need to create my own Crystal report and call it in java (NB).

Comment: Jasper Reports. it's kinda easy than iReport for me. so maybe i'll use JasperReports. thank you sir.

Comment: No worries, maman. I think it's not worth all the extra hassle to try and use Crystal Reports for java. Good luck with iReports and if my answer helped you, please don't forget to upvote or mark as answer. Cheers!